# PYTZ always 7 hours ahead

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, discord, pytz

so I'm trying to make a discord bot in python and make a command that will display all timezones that I choose, but the problem is that all of these timezones are around 7-8 hours ahead of normal.

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

localFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, %Z%z"

UTC=datetime.datetime.utcnow()

timezonelist = ["US/Eastern", "US/Central", "US/Mountain", "US/Pacific", "Etc/UTC", "Europe/Berlin", "Australia/North", "Australia/South", "Australia/West"]

for tz in timezonelist:
    localDatetime = UTC.astimezone(timezone(tz))
    x = localDatetime.strftime(localFormat)
    print(tz + " " + x)
```

for example, Etc/UTC outputs 05:56:25 when it should output 22:56:25, other timezones follow this example, EST outputs 00:56:25 when it should be 17:56:25, or MST (where I am), 22:56:25 instead of 15:56:25. However, `datetime.utcnow()` returns the correct time.

I had done some research and it said that PYTZ uses the LMT but since all are forward by an amount I do not think it has to do with that.

Comment: btw. LMT (local mean time) is the state of a pytz timezone object *before* you attach it to a datetime object with `astimezone` or `localize`. It will only  stay LMT if you use datetime's `replace` method - which you just should not use if you use pytz. With dateutil or zoneinfo timezone objects, you don't have to worry about that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utcnow()` gives you a naive datetime object - it is not aware that it's in UTC although the numbers *show* UTC. If you convert to another time zone, Python will assume all naive datetime objects are *local time*. Your local time (MST) is UTC-7, that's why you're off by 7 hours.

The behaviour of utcnow is confusing and can lead to unexpected results - [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html). Instead, use `now()` and set the tz explicitly:

```
UTC = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
```